# How to create a script tag helper that inherits from the standard .Net Core script tag helper

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I maintain a large legacy ASP.NET MVC application, which was recently converted to .Net Core.

I need to introduce cache busting for our JavaScript and CSS files. I appreciate this can easily be done using the *asp-append-version="true"* attribute on the new .Net Core script tag helper.

However, my application has script tags in over a 100 places. Adding the attribute in all those places will touch large numbers of pages, which means a lot of regression testing.

Is there a way to create a new script tag helper that inherits from the .Net Core script tag helper, and that always has the *asp-append-version="true"* attribute? That will give me cache busting without having to update lots of files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger TagHelper from another TagHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857188/trigger-taghelper-from-another-taghelper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...create a new script tag helper that inherits from the .Net Core script tag helper, and that always has the asp-append-version="true" attribute?

#### Code ([View on GitHub](https://github.com/bigfont/AspNetCoreScriptTagHelperOverride))

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace AspNetCoreScriptTagHelperOverride
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("script")] // A
    public class MyScriptTagHelper : ScriptTagHelper
    {
        public MyScriptTagHelper(
            IHostingEnvironment env,
            IMemoryCache cache,
            HtmlEncoder html,
            JavaScriptEncoder js,
            IUrlHelperFactory url) : base(env, cache, html, js, url) { } // B

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            const string appendVersion = "asp-append-version";
            if (!context.AllAttributes.Any(a => a.Name == appendVersion))
            {
                var attributes = new TagHelperAttributeList(context.AllAttributes);
                attributes.Add(appendVersion, true);
                context = new TagHelperContext(attributes, context.Items, context.UniqueId);
            } // E

            base.AppendVersion = true; // C
            base.Process(context, output); // D
        }
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

- A: Set the `TagName` to `"script"`.
- B: Implement the base constructor.
- C: Hard code `AppendVersion` to true.
- D: Call the base class's `Process`.
- E: Overcome [`AttributeMatcher.TryDetermineMode`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/ScriptTagHelper.cs#L225)

#### Usage

In `_ViewImports.cshtml` [remove the existing tag helper and add your override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.1#managing-tag-helper-scope).

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ScriptTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AspNetCoreScriptTagHelperOverride
```

Be sure to use the name of your *assembly*.

Once that is done, your code will execute wherever there is a `script` tag helper. For instance, both of the following will have `AppendVersion` set to `true`.

```
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="false"></script>
```

This will be the the resultant HTML:

```
<script src="/js/site.js?v=4q1jwFhaPaZgr8WAUSrux6hAuh0XDg9kPS3xIVq36I0"></script>
```

#### See Also

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/ScriptTagHelper.cs

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't work. I created a small test app with plain script tags, and this tag helper did not modify those script tags at all.

Comment: Fixed. And here is a sample https://github.com/bigfont/AspNetCoreScriptTagHelperOverride

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Did notice that if the tag already has an asp-append-version attribute, this tag helper somehow adds a second src attribute to the tag. But Chrome completely ignores that second src attribute, so its not really an issue.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the @removeTagHelper to my _ViewImports.cshtml. It now works perfectly, without a second src being added.